# how to apply ngModel to an input field using Angular

Tags: angular, ngmodel

Hey Guys im new in Angular,as far as i know ngModel is for two way binding right?so if i have 2 input box,can i bind one to another,so when i type something on one of them at the same time first one gets updated?

```
        <form >
    <div>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="test" id="test1" >
    <input type="text" id="test" ">
    </div>
    </form>
```

i want when i write something on the second input box with the id "test" the first one shows it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can. Just use same `ngModel` in inputs.
Like that:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="test" id="test1" >
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="test" id="test2" >
```

Comment: what about the name attribute?because i get error now

Comment: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="test" id="test1" name="tata">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="test" id="test2" [attr.name]="test">
- no error here

Comment: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

Comment: If ngForm is used, all the input fields which has [(ngModel)]="" must have an attribute name with a value.
<input [(ngModel)]="firstname" name="something">

Answer (score 3):

Event though Tony Marko already answered your quesiton. I would like to add couple of details. First of all, ngModel can be used in different cases. For example

1st. Initialize FormControl instance on the input

```
// Creates FormControl with a name firstName and template ref firstName
// So FormControl props can be used in your template
// for example *ngIf="firstName.valid"
<input ngModel name="firstName" #firstName="ngModel">
```

2nd. One way value binding

```
// Value of the input changes as soon as IMMUTABLE component property changes
<input [ngModel]="firstName" name="firstName">
```

3rd. Two way binding

```
// The same as before but also changes property on input change
<input [(ngModel)]="firstName" name="firstName">
```

4th. Separated two way binding

```
// Its 100% identical as previous, but event emitter is separated
// Which allows you to do side action onModelChange event
<input [ngModel]="firstName" (ngModelChange)="firstName = $event" name="firstName">
```

I hope it clarifies your answer

Comment: yes that was very great because it was not so clear why i need a ID and also name,now i think i got the point

Comment: Good. You can remove name attribute and Angular will let you know that it's missing.